# Counterexample to show homeomorphic spaces don't need to have the same dense subsets

Tags: general-topology

Given a set $X$ with two homeomorphic topologies $\mathcal{T}_1$ and $\mathcal{T}_2$ on X. Consider the statement:

> A subset $U \subseteq X$ is dense in $\mathcal{T}_1$ *iff* $U$ is dense in $\mathcal{T}_2$.

I know this statement is false but I need to find a 2-element set $X$ which proves that it's false.

while making sure the topologies are homeomorphic.

Comment: What do you mean "homeomorphic topologies?"

Comment: This is a very bizarre condition to ask about.

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to functional analysis. I meant if (X,T1) is homeomorphic to (X,T2),

Comment: There are only four topologies on a two-element set, and, of those, only two are homeomorphic.  This is a very instructive question to approach through brute force.

Answer (score 5):

Let $X = \{a,b\}$, take $T_1 = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, X\}$ and $T_2 = \{\emptyset, \{b\}, X\}$, and let $U = \{a\}$.

Then $(X,T_1)$ is homeomorphic to $(X,T_2)$ by the map swapping $a$ and $b$, but $U$ is dense in $(X,T_1)$, while $U$ is not dense in $(X,T_2)$ (no element of $U$ is contained in the open set $\{b\}$).

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be the set of natural numbers.  Let $T_1$ be the topology generated by the set of all singletons $\{n\}$ with $n > 0$, and let $T_2$ be the topology generated the the set of all singletons $\{m\}$ with $m > 100$.

The two topologies are homeomorphic (via the map taking $n$ to $n+100$), but the set of numbers greater than $100$ is dense in $T_2$, but not in $T_1$.